# How to configure mosquitto broker with IP

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I wantmy mosquitto MQTT broker to be connect as IP instead of localhost. Currently I tried to modify the mosquitto.conf with:

```
listener 1883 0.0.0.0
```

But it doesn't work, it keep showing `disconnected from server`:

My full conf file : https://justpaste.it/1rdep

[image]

Comment: You need to either supply a username/password or allow anonymous connections as well as binding to something other than localhost.

Comment: @hardillb Thanks for ur respond, i allow anonymous and it worked. I remember last time no need to turn on the anonymous right ？

Comment: Read the release notes linked to in the accepted answer on the duplicate